# How do I clear and replace values of a deque with list values?

Tags: python, deque

Let's say I have a list with six items

```
app = [6, 4, 6, 22, 255, 33]
```

But I want to pass those numbers to an argument - but only 3 numbers at a time

How would I do that?

Right now I'm using a deque with a max limit, but I don't know how to swap out the values with the next set.

Comment: What's wrong with a simple slice?

Comment: I'm still learning; so I didn't know about those.

Comment: Slices are a fundamental part of Python syntax for handling sequences like strings, tuples and lists. I would learn those before messing with a deque.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with loop:

```
app = [6, 4, 6, 22, 255, 33]

for i in range(0, len(app), 3):
   print(app[i], app[i+1], app[i+2])
```

Solution with zip:

```
app = [6, 4, 6, 22, 255, 33]

for (i, j, q) in zip(app[::3], app[1::3], app[2::3]):
    print(i, j, q)
```

More general solution. `Grouper` from [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
from itertools import izip_longest

app = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)


for i, j, q, r in grouper(app, 4):
    print(i, j, q, r)
```

Comment: I like the two solutions, but what if I don't know the length of the list, and I have numbers left over?  - like if I wanted slices with 4 numbers each instead of 3?

Comment: @StackJohan Add to my answer solution for your comment

Comment: That's really impressive! I'll definitely read more about the `zip` feature

Answer (score 2):

You can use the subarray notation of Python. E.g. `app[:3]` for the first three elements, or `app[1:4]` (= `[4, 6, 22]`) for the second to the fourth element.

If your function expects three parameters, you can pass them with the `*` operator:

```
def f(a, b, c):
    ...

f(*app[:3])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use python slices. Code written in browser, not tested

It does create a new array, but it is a small array

```
for i in range(len(app)-3):
    slice = app[i:i+3]
    myfun(slice[0], slice[1], slice[2])
```